# Runtime VS Driver API in Cuda

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, nvidia

It's common to use the runtime API in function calls when programming with CUDA. Different sources insist in the fact that the performance of both APIs is nearly the same, and it's better to focus in memory use and thread organization to improve the performance. So what would be the real difference between the two APIs ?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the CUDA documentation: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/driver-vs-runtime-api.html#driver-vs-runtime-api

> 1. Difference between the driver and runtime APIs
>
>    The driver and runtime APIs are very similar and can for the most part be used
>    interchangeably. However, there are some key differences worth noting
>    between the two.
>
>    Complexity vs. control
>
>    The runtime API eases device code management by
>    providing implicit initialization, context management, and module
>    management. This leads to simpler code, but it also lacks the level of
>    control that the driver API has.